# RVO (Return Value Optimization) doesn't explain this mystery

Tags: c++

Simple program:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace::std;


class X {
    public:
        X() {
            cout << "Default Constructor called\n";
            i = 0;
        }


        X(int i) {
            cout << "Parameterized Constructor called\n";
            this->i = i;
        }
        X(const X& x) {
            cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
            i = x.getI();
        }
        ~X() {
            cout << "Destructor called\n";
        }
        int getI() const {
            return i;
        }
        X func() {
            cout << "Entered func\n";
            X x(2);
            return x;
        }
    private:
        int i;
};

int main() {
     X x1;
     X x2 = x1.func();
    cout << "Returned from func\n";    
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
Default Constructor called
Entered func
Parameterized Constructor called
Copy Constructor called
Destructor called
Returned from func
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

***After the 'Returned from func' is printed, no constructor is called when creating the instance x2. I was actually expecting a copy constructor to be called when instantiating x2 as it would have been if we did something like `X x2 = x1;`***

Now, I was told that this is a result of RVO. Is it true?

In wiki, RVO is defined as:

> Return value optimization, or simply RVO, is a compiler optimization technique that involves eliminating the temporary object created to hold a function's return value.

**But, I don't buy this for two reasons:**

1.x2 here is not a temporary object.
2. If it were really to be the case, then the compiler would have been much better off implementing RVO when x was being returned from the function. That was a genuine case of a temporary object (during the return statement).

So, please explain why x2 was not instantiated after the function returned an object of X.

Comment: `Returned from func` gets printed after construction of `x2` is complete, the copy constructor call is visible in the output you've shown 2 lines above it. I'm surprised you even see that copy constructor call because NRVO should've [eliminated that copy](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69b190cd491306bc).

Comment: "Copy Constructor called" it's called right ?

Comment: Observe carefully. That is called after the 'func entered' is printed. That means that it got called from within the function, i.e. it was referring to the instance x, not x2.

Comment: Why should there be an additional constructor after the `returned from function` line , when that is the last line of your code?

Comment: @TheVigilanteSting Then what is `Parameterized Constructor called` referring to if `Copy Constructor called` refers to construction of `x` (and how is that a copy construction)?

Comment: What makes you so sure, that that copy isn`t elided and what you are seeing is the copy construction of x2? Btw: when compiling with g++, the copy constructor is never called (even in -o0)

Comment: Using a sensible compiler (say gcc), and comparing -fno-elide-constructors to the default mode, you see there are normally 2 copies done, x to retval, and retval to x2. Both can be elided.

Comment: In general, a brute-force alternative to spending a lot of time understanding RVO in C++97 and C++11 is simply to return data through smart pointers or send in a reference to the function. I like simplicity more than elegance. R-value references are also notoriously hard to understand perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to see what's happening if you get your functions to output more precise information.  Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    X() : i_(0) { std::cout << "X(" << this << ")\n"; }
    X(int i) : i_(i) { std::cout << "X(" << this << ", i " << i << ")\n"; }
    X(const X& rhs) : i_(rhs.i_) { std::cout << "X(" << this << ", const X& "
                                             << &rhs << ")\n"; }
    ~X() { std::cout << "~X(" << this << ")\n"; }
    X func() { std::cout << "X::func(this " << this << ")\n"; X x(2); return x; }
    int i_;
};

int main()
{
    X x1;
    X x2 = x1.func();
    std::cout << "x1 " << &x1 << ", x2 " << &x2 << '\n';
}
```

Output on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/gO2hIa) was:

```
X(0xbfd346e8)
X::func(this 0xbfd346e8)
X(0xbfd346ec, i 2)
x1 0xbfd346e8, x2 0xbfd346ec
~X(0xbfd346ec)
~X(0xbfd346e8)
```

That shows full RVO and elided copy-construction, which will be typical of most compilers at normal production optimisation levels (and quite possibly even lower levels).

I suggest you run the above code on your compiler with whatever flags you've been using, and the addresses displayed should make it clearer to you exactly which objects are involved in the various operations you've observed.  As is, your comments...

> Observe carefully. That is called after the 'func entered' is printed. That means that it got called from within the function, i.e. it was referring to the instance x, not x2.

...is flawed logic (with more attitude to boot *"I'll just wait for someone who actually understands copy constructors to answer this."*), which the better logging should help you realise.  (Then hopefully you'll apologise to Praetorian.)